# recycling higher dimensional arrays

Tags: r

I was surprised to find that R's recycling didn't apply in higher dimensions:

```
> str(Z)
 num [1:5, 1:100, 1:10] 1.02 0.989 2.555 1.167 -0.835 ...
> str(w)
 num [1:5, 1:100] 1.43 7.84 6.13 2.91 2.8 ...
> Z + w
Error in Z + w : non-conformable arrays
```

whereas I expected the 2d matrix `w` to be recycled along the 3rd dimension of `Z`. I get the same error with a matrix `w` with dimensions like the last 2 of `Z` (as with numpy's broadcasting rule). I figured when recycling R would simply flatten each array in the order of the dimensions (C style) and add them, then reshape them back, which would work in however many dimensions. Is there a right way to recycle a matrix like I'm trying to? I guess I could do the flattening and reshaping myself by manipulating the dim attributes, but obviously would prefer not to do the work myself.

The language definition has this line:  "That is, if for instance you add c(1, 2, 3) to a six-element vector then you will really add c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)." Can anyone who has looked under the hood tell me whether R is literally creating a new longer vector from the shorter, to conform the the other operand, and then applying the operator? I had been assuming recycling was more space-efficient. If not then I might as well achieve the higher-dimensional recycling by creating a 3-way array from the matrix. I imagine there is some package for multiway arrays/tensors but I would prefer to use base.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit recycling only works with vectors. A solution to matrix recycling is to use the sweep function, as documented [here](http://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/043zwg3tff/r-array-addition-doesnt-recycle#20040331fb9a680p0ek4kragmzvrs26y14). In your case, try

```
sweep(Z,1:2,w,FUN="+")
```

The second argument specifies which dimensions of Z will be preserved.